# Multiboot System Advice?

Tags: partitioning, dual-boot, distro-recommendation

I'm thinking about doing a multiboot install on my laptop. I have 250GB of HDD space.

I want my main partition to be Ubuntu, and I want to keep everything on there (Media, preferences, etc.) rather than having a dedicated home partition. Am I able to, for example, let OpenSUSE access my Ubuntu partition and read /ubuntu/home/user/music as opensuse/home/user/music? Can this also be done for preferences for applications, such as LibreOffice?

I have that feeling that this won't work, but I figured it's worth a shot.

Also, I'm considering using Fedora, OpenSUSE, Debian, and Linux Mint as my alternative distros. This is probably unrelated, but does anyone else recommend better distros to replace/go alongside these? Finally, what are recommended install sizes for these distros if I'm not going to be putting media on them?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can this also be done for preferences for applications, such as LibreOffice?

Yes. That is both a good and a bad thing though. If different distributions using the same applications but different versions, sometimes the configuration can be updated so that is no longer backwards compatible with older versions. One example: Banshee is notoriously inflexible when it comes to config versions. If you install a PPA version and try to go back, you have to nuke your config database.

Firefox can get a little twitchy about its plugins if you jump between major versions but it tends to soldier on. And a lot of other applications tend to just work.

---

But speaking in the wider sense, why would you want to "live" in that many different distributions? I'd go mad trying to remember which I was in and dealing with that many various hardware issues. Yak!

If you just need to do things in the other occasionally, I'd strongly consider leaving your home in your main OS, symlinking/bind-mounting when you need something (like /music), leaving the rest of your profile alone and then just virtualising the less essential operating systems with VirtualBox, XEN or another HV.

Comment: my biggest reason for wanting at least one more distro is because i want a fallback incase i crash Ubuntu. But, you do have a point. I probably don't want too many boots!

Thank you for your answer about preferences!!!